# Bootstrap: How to make navbar two layered on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a navigation bar with brand name and search box on left side and menus on right side.

Here is the [bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/5JpNhRw9cu)

This is good on large screens, but on small screen, I want to display this as two bars on top, first one with the left content (brand name and search bar) and second one with the right content (menus). Can I do this just using bootstrap classes?

Comment: Do you mean you want two toggles like this: http://www.bootply.com/jme11/3bnOBdLHve#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/cUrZckyHSo)

Use `hidden` class

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

                    <div class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-md hidden-lg" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be acheived by add another button for collapsing, look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t1ppLrzy/2/) , other things will be ur work around

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
```